# Job/task queue manager for Windows

Tags: windows

I'm after a simple GUI to launch a bunch of scripts/applications **in sequence** (no scheduling).
A kind of simple visual task/queue launcher/manager.
Searching for this on the web is very difficult: the terms "job queue", "task", "manager" are so widely used !